# How to load multiple objects (list of list) in HDF5?

Tags: python, keras, hdf5

I am currently trying to use keras to predict ... stuffs. I am using a HDF5  file as input. The file contains 195 objects, each one is a list of matrices with one attribute. I would like keras to learn on the list of matrices and predict the attribute. But here is the issue, so far I have seen that one object can only be assigned to one variable. That would be meaningless in my case.

I would like to know whether or not it was possible to load all of these objects at once, say under one variable, in keras to predict the attribute ? For instance here are some objects,

```
['10gs', '1a30', '1bcu',..., '4tmn']
```

I know I can assign one variable to one object,

```
dataset=infile['1a30']
```

However I am not sure how to assign several objects to one variable? Do I need to create a list of objects ? Here's what I am trying to get,

```
dataset=infile['all of my objects'].
```

In fine, I will be using it in keras but I am not too sure whether it is necessary as it seems to me it is a HDF file issue (misunderstanding).

Comment: Formatting code

Comment: This question is about programming basics, yes, you need to make a list, but I don't think there is enough detail here to answer, what are the objects inside the HDF5 that you are talking about?

Comment: Hi DijkGraad ! Hi Matias ! Thank you for taking the time to answer.  @MatiasValdenegro; The objects are list of list. essentially I have something like; [[x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, float_01, float_02, float_03, ..., float_19, type32], [x_coords, y_coords, z_coords, float_01, float_02, float_03, ..., float_19, type32]...]. If you are curious these are physico_chemical informations for atoms. The first 3 floats describes the coordinates, then the 19 floats describes atomic information. The first array encodes for atom 1, then the second for atom 2 and so on.

Comment: Based on your code syntax, I assume you are using `h5py`? You should investigate numpy arrays. This is typically what you will get when you use `h5py` or `pytables` to read a HDF5 table (dataset). Frankly these are much easier to use than lists (IMHO). `dataset=infile['1a30'][:]` is returned as a numpy array, and you reference an element with slice notation like this `dataset[row_range,column_range]`. You can also slice entire rows or columns.